# Can anyone write this code in optimized way?

Tags: soql, governorlimits, dynamic-soql

**I know it's not the correct way to write the code like this. But can anyone help me to optimize this code without for loop?**

```
    String userName = 'test@test.com%';
    List<String> objectNames = new List<String> {'Product_Label__c', 'Line_Item__c', 'Country__c', 'Regieon__c', 'Product_Group__c'};
    Integer count = 0;

    for (String objectName : objectNames){
    count = Database.countQuery('SELECT Count() FROM ' objectName + ' WHERE LastModifiedDate > YESTERDAY AND LastModifiedBy.username LIKE :userName');
        System.debug(objectName+'---->'+count);
        if (count > 0) {
            break;
        }

    }
    if(count==0){
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't optimize the query to support multiple SObjects at once.

If you have just a few supported types it's ok to just do SOQL in the loop.

If you need to query more than a hundred types at once (when you start to run into SOQL limits) then you can split your queries into chunks and do multiple requests to the controller and then aggregate results on UI